# плохой рендеринг в unity

Tags: unity3d

Всем добра.

Делаю проект типа rts, сделал движение камеры свайпом и все бы не чего, пока не обратил внимание как плавно идет отрисовка в коммерческой игре. Разница просто огромна, и дело не в том что там камера плавно двигается а сама отрисовка плавно идет.

Я сделал два видеo, на первом я тяну камеру по экрану, и желтый примитив он как будто трясется, особенно видно при быстром перемещении.
Как будто рендеринг не успевает или что то около этого.

На втором видео двигаю камерy и там все плавно, при любой скорости сдвига,
опять повторюсь, реч не о плавности движения самой камеры, а об отрисовке.

Как добиться такого?

Я всю юню облазил, все настройки перетыкал. В интернете ни чего не нашел, я бы даже сказал глухо. Нашел кучу советов по оптимизации или улучшении графики которые так и ничего не дали.

Как улучшить этот нищебродский рендер.

Хоть бы кто подсказал что на это влияет, а то может это и не рендеринг вовсе.

мой проект
  https://gfycat.com/unrulyscentedhuia?

нормальный проект
   https://gfycat.com/apprehensiveillegalladybug?

```
   void LateUpdate(){


        if(!canSlider || PermitManager.i.ELEMENT_UI) return;


        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            hit_position = Input.mousePosition * sensitive;
            camera_position = transform.position;
            lastPosition = transform.position;

        }
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            current_position = Input.mousePosition * sensitive;
            LeftMouseDrag();        
        }



    }

   void LeftMouseDrag(){
        // From the Unity3D docs: "The z position is in world units from the camera."  In my case I'm using the y-axis as height
        // with my camera facing back down the y-axis.  You can ignore this when the camera is orthograhic.
        current_position.z = hit_position.z = camera_position.y;

        // Get direction of movement.  (Note: Don't normalize, the magnitude of change is going to be Vector3.Distance(current_position-hit_position)
        // anyways.  
        Vector3 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(current_position) - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(hit_position);

        // Invert direction to that terrain appears to move with the mouse.
        direction = direction * -1;


        position = camera_position + direction;

        position.y = startPos.y;

        position = checkPosition(position);

        transform.position = position;
    }
```

Comment: частоту кадров до 60 поднимать пробовали?

Comment: @Александр Даниловский в самой юнити?

Comment: Можете в профайлере посмотреть куда ресурсы тратятся. В 2018.2: Window-Analysis-Profiler.

Comment: @Roman, да в Unity/

Comment: @Roman, еще хотелось бы посмотреть на код, которым Вы двигаете камеру. Помимо частоты кадров проблема может быть в коде. Камеры рекомендуется перемещать в методе [LateUpdate()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html)

Comment: @ trollingchar а зачем профайлер? датчики показывают 60 fps на 8 айфоне.
Не думаю что сейчас стоит смотреть профайлер, сцена ведь пуста, там кроме пары примитивов и нескольких скриптов ничего нет.

Comment: Ситуация немного улучшилась, я бы даже сказал серьезно улучшилась.

@Александр Даниловский смена update на lateUpdate ни чего не дала.

quality setting у меня на medium,
при этом полностью отключены тени и свет запечен. 
anti aliasing тоже отключен, за ненадобностью.
добавил в start скипта Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
и о чудо, камера теперь двигается легко, а раньше как будто через lerp или smooth, хотя позиция напрямую передавалась.
Ну и картинка при перемещении улучшилась, более четче стало, но все еще не так как хотелось бы.